# Android NDK plugin installation in eclipse SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-plugin, android-ndk

When I am trying to install Android NDK plugin from

> Android Developer Tools Update Site -
>   https://dl.google.com/android/eclipse/

in my Eclipse, it is showing the the following error message - I am using Android Developer Tools from Google, Build: v22.6.2-1085508. And I have downloaded android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86_64.

```
'Installing Software' has encountered a problem.

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk,22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk,22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206
```

I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 7):

Just change the URL to https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

It solved.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can follow below steps

step 1: download ndk from this url https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

step 2: Extract the downloaded sdk

step 3: open eclipse and browse the NDK
window->perference->android->NDK->browse your ndk

Answer (score 2):

Just instal Developer Tools (`Help -> Instal New Software -> http:////dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`).
Dowload [NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html). Extract it.
Then go to `Window -> Preferences -> Android -> NDK -> And set NDK path`