# NDK is not listed at the update page, why?

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, eclipse-plugin, android-ndk

I am trying to install the NDK plugin for eclipse in order to use OpenCV.

I am following this [tutorial (at step 6)](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html#android-dev-intro). This [stack-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118098/android-ndk-plugin-installation-in-eclipse-sdk) also indicates that the way I try to install NDK appears to be the right one. Saldy eclipse **does not show me the NDK plugin available** at the right update site. (https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)

I already ensured, that I do have CDT installed.

My elcipse version is the following:

```
Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800
```

**What can I do to install the NDK plugin for eclipse?**

Comment: I will try now to do an installation withuot the update page:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting


I see exactly the same packages as on the official download page but NDK is not offered.

Comment: Don't use Eclipse, check out [this video on using the NDK with Android Studio](https://software.intel.com/en-us/videos/using-the-ndk-with-android-studio).

Comment: I nowed copied the jars into dropins and it worked.